# Which one is better to use in Apache Spark NA Functions, Replace or Fill?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Apache Spark Na Functions has `fill` and `replace`. `fill` function deal with `null` values. But I can use `replace` function to replace null values as well. Which one is better and why?

Comment: You also have `replace` available with [`DataFrameNaFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html).

Comment: Yes. I am talking about this one.

Answer (score 1):

fill function meant for replacing null and NaN values only where as replace function can replace any literal value with another.

According to doc:

// Returns a new `DataFrame` that replaces null or NaN values in numeric columns with
value`.

df.na.fill(23);

// Replaces all occurrences of 1.0 with 2.0 in column "height".

df.na.replace("height", ImmutableMap.of(1.0, 2.0));

So, in replace function you can NOT replace null values with some literal.